# How to remove box shadow from overlapping elements

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKFb1.jpg)I have some html which is causing a box shadow in mobile view. I didn't put it there and I've tried everything to get rid of it. It only shows up in mobile view but I suspect its there because I'm inserting all the text in one place and then moving it left.

Html:

```
<div class="b">t</div>
<div class="c">n</div>
<div class="d">a</div>
<div class="e">t</div>
<div class="f">l</div>
<div class="g">u</div>
<div class="h">s</div>
<div class="i">n</div>
<div class="j">o</div>
<div class="k">c</div>
<div class="l">n</div>
<div class="m">g</div>
<div class="n">i</div>
<div class="o">s</div>
<div class="p">e</div>
<div class="q">d</div>
</div>
```

And

```
    </div><div id="text-7" class="widget widget_text">          <div class="textwidget"><div class="line-down">
```

Tried altering the id css:

```
#text-7 {box-shadow: none}
```

Didn't work.

You can view [here](http://4309.co.uk)

Here is Codepen but I can't seem to reproduce the problem https://codepen.io/adsler/pen/rXoNGJ

Comment: What browser are you referring to? Also please make a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem. Does the problem happen in actual mobile browsers like iOS Safari and Chrome on Android?

Comment: Yes. In chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `.n {box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;}` in your css which creates that box-shadow. Search your css for that using `CTRL+F`.

Consider using `svg` or other formats instead of creating your complex illustration with divs. The nesting is incredibly dirty.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks dude. Yeah, I'm still learning. Learnt how to make a ruler today using html/css. :-) Have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

The box-shadow is caused by this css rule

```css
.n {box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #808080;}
```

I'ld suggest to remove or override it with some more specific css

```css
body .n {box-shadow: none;}
```

or just inline:

```html
<div style="box-shadow:none;" class="n">i</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

And @mertcanb is right, your markup is a mess ;)

Comment: Thanks. Yes. Silly me. :-) gave you an up vote but doesn't show cus not enough points.